# Load specific elements from XML into textbox/combobox/NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I currently have a combobox `cbxID` which displays All StudentID's and would like to send different elements into different textboxes/comboboxes/NumericUpDown while pressing the button Load.

The Load button should take the currently selected StudentID and then send the Informations into the right box.

```
  <Student>
    <StudentID>207</StudentID> //supposed to go into txtStudentID
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName> // -->txtFirstName
    <LastName>Smith</LastName> // -->txtLastName
    <SchoolClass>10</SchoolClass> // -->txtSchoolClass
    <Age>17</Age> //-->nudAge (numericupdown)
    <Height>186</Height //-->nudHeight
    <Gender>male</Gender> //-->combobox
  </Student>
```

I'm using this code to display the ID's into the combobox

```
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(FilePath);
            this.cbxStudentIDs.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            this.cbxStudentIDs.DisplayMember = "ID";
        }
```

Comment: You can get the datarow : DataRow row = dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("StudentID") == cmxStudentIDs.Text).FirstOrDefault();  Not sure why your code is using "ID" when the xml has "StudentID".

Comment: I get this error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException:`

Comment: Where did you get the exception?  My code will not work if the combobox has no items nor will it work if there are no tables in the dataset.  Looks like Jack fixed what I found earlier and changed "ID" to "StudentID" like I said above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to load the button to receive the currently

selected student ID,and send different elements to different message box when you press the button to load.

You can try the following code to solve this problem.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string FilePath = "D:\\student.xml";        

        public Form1()
        {       
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(FilePath);
            DataRow row = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("StudentID") == cbxStudentIDs.Text).FirstOrDefault();
            txtStudentID.Text = row["StudentID"].ToString();
            txtFirstName.Text = row["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLastName.Text = row["LastName"].ToString();
            txtSchoolClass.Text = row["SchoolClass"].ToString();
            nudAge.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Age"]);
            nudHeight.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Height"]);
            comboBox1.Text= row["Gender"].ToString();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(FilePath);
            cbxStudentIDs.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
            cbxStudentIDs.DisplayMember = "StudentID";

        }
    }
```

I used the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDaten xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Student>
    <StudentID>207</StudentID> 
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName> 
    <LastName>Smith</LastName> 
    <SchoolClass>10</SchoolClass> 
    <Age>17</Age> 
    <Height>186</Height>
    <Gender>male</Gender> 
  </Student>
 <Student>
    <StudentID>208</StudentID> 
    <FirstName>fei</FirstName> 
    <LastName>meng</LastName> 
    <SchoolClass>12</SchoolClass> 
    <Age>19</Age> 
    <Height>178</Height>
    <Gender>male</Gender> 
  </Student>
 <Student>
    <StudentID>209</StudentID> 
    <FirstName>qiu</FirstName> 
    <LastName>Song</LastName> 
    <SchoolClass>12</SchoolClass> 
    <Age>18</Age> 
    <Height>165</Height>
    <Gender>female</Gender> 
  </Student>
<Student>
    <StudentID>210</StudentID> 
    <FirstName>yiyi</FirstName> 
    <LastName>Yao</LastName> 
    <SchoolClass>11</SchoolClass> 
    <Age>18</Age> 
    <Height>168</Height>
    <Gender>female</Gender> 
  </Student>
</ArrayOfDaten>
```

This is my tested result:

[image]

Comment: You're an absolute legend! Thank you very much :)